# Adding Custom Application into Outlook

Tags: asp.net, vba, outlook, outlook-addin

Want to add a button into Outlook for users in our company so people can select an email and click "Add to System". This will popup a form which will allow them to fill in some details and than save the email into our internal CRM program. The internal CRM package is an ASP.net mvc app with a SQL Server DB backend so we can pass the data from outlook straight to the DB or pass into a web service.

Any advice on whether this is possible and any examples out there?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an Outlook addin. You will then be able to return to Outlook custom XML describing your ribbon and buttons.

Start at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=36